# How to change the apache user for a virtual host in Centos 7?

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am trying to set up a web server on Centos 7. I have created a virtual host by editing /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. The root directory of the virtual host was set to /var/www/html/domain.com. I am able to open domain.com in the browser with no issue.

However, when I use get_current_user() in a PHP file to test what user the server is running under, the output is "root" which is a security concernt.

How do I change the user of the virtual host? When I set up a similar scenario in Ubuntu, I used apache2-mpm-itk module and configured the virtual host with "AssignUserID your_username your_username" and it did the trick. But I don't know how to do it in Centos.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use SuexecUserGroup for that.

I found this method from plesk's configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup "anyuser" "anygroup"
    </IfModule>

/VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache cant' restart after that :(

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS, this command gives you the file's owner, not the owner of the process ID. Something like that. It's in the PHP manual. Check out the comments at the bottom. [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php)  By the way, check your `User` and `Group` directives in the httpd.conf and in httpd-vhost.conf. Also, use `ps -faux` to get a clear idea of the process spawning relationships between the httpd binary and the children it spawns. Just trying to help. ;-)

Also, check out [How Apache Starts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/invoking.html) at the top of this page to make sure you understand how Apache is supposed to work by default. If yours in not working this way, that may be a good thing to know!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7 you can use the httpd-itk package. It is in the EPEL repository, so you need to add that first. Something like this should get it:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install httpd-itk
```

Once installed you need to load the module by uncommenting the LoadModule line in:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm-itk.conf
```

Restart the httpd, and then you can use the new AssignUserID directive inside your VirtualHost sections.

Comment: Unfortunately in Cento 7 it doesn't work:

    yum install apache-itk 
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
    No package apache-itk available.

Comment: @Lisitso Sorry, I got the package name wrong in the actual commands. It should be httpd-itk. I've fixed it in the response.

Answer (score -1):

have you looked into which user/group is specified in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf?  It would look something like this:

`User apache
Group apache`

Comment: Yes. The content of httpd.conf: "User apache Group apache"